# Windows service cannot access json file

Tags: c#

Within my windows service, there is a method that will read a JSON file ( that I manually created) and later process it. The problem is that, the service starts, but the moment it needs to check if the file exist ( at a given path), the service simply stays stuck at the "if" line.(No errors are being thrown, nothing). I decided to test the exact same method in a windows console project and it's working perfectly (it checks if the file exists and even gets the json content). Below follows the earlier described method:

```
//   
 private string ReadJsonFile()
    {
        string jsonResponse = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            string networkPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("networkPath");
            string fileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("jsonFileName");

            new DoLog("Program has executed this line");
            if (File.Exists(networkPath + fileName)) 
// the moment the program hits the above line, it wont continue
            {
                 new DoLog("Program has entered the IF clause");
                 jsonResponse = File.ReadAllText(networkPath + fileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            jsonResponse = string.Empty;
            new DoLog(e.Message);
        }

        return jsonResponse;
    }
```

Below follows my app.config file

```
<add key="networkPath" value="C:\TestFlightImporting\"/>
<add key="jsonFileName" value ="retest.json"/>
```

As stated before, the "ReadJsonFile()" method works perfectly in a console application, but the moment I run it within a windows service, it stays stuck at the line of "if(File.Exists())". Can anybody please help me with this weird issue? Thank you in advance

P.S:  The class of DoLog's only job is to write at a log file what's happening within the program.

Comment: What user does the windows service run as?  It probably doesn't have access.

Comment: @Amy I ran the service as Administrator, but I should note that my PC is on a domain network. With other words i ran the service as Administrator ( right click on the service --> properties --> Click on the tab of "Log On")   or even with my DOmain account. Both of them are giving the same issue.. I'm suspecting that the problem lies with my pc being in a Domain Network

Comment: Are you sure the file is not open?  Check Task Manager.

Comment: @slaphshot33324 : yes, I've checked multiple times

Comment: Try restarting the computer the file is on.

Comment: When things don't appear to make sense, begin challenging what we think we know.  Are the configuration keys in the question part of the services configuration?  Log them from your code.  Are the paths in the question the *actual* paths used by both the service and your local?

Comment: @Amy: yes, with the help of the logging class I was able to verify that keys and path were correct. I decided to do something out of the box, which was to allow the service to run as Administrator ( right click on the .exe --> properties --> Compatibility tab --> "check" the checkbox of "run this program as an administrator".. that immediately solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: For now the only way that this problem was solved is by running the service administrator rights. [image: set admin rights for the service via properties]